# `ulimit -n` for non-root

Tags: launchd, resources

I'm running El Capitan / Mac OSX 10.11.6 (15G1108) and I want to increase the "Max Open files" for some of my terminals / bash sessions. I'm logged in with my normal users. I read through all the guides I could find and managed to increase some limits:

As my user:

```
$ launchctl limit maxfiles
    maxfiles    200000         200000
```

But, when I try to set the limit, I fail:

```
$ ulimit -n 8096
-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

The strange thing is that I actually can set the ulimit if I switch to root:

```
$ sudo bash
$ ulimit -n 9086
```

Now of course, running everything as root is stupid, so I'm searching for a better solution. How can I allow my user to also increase his "Max Files Limit"?

What I have done already:

```
$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf
kern.maxfiles=65536
kern.maxfilesperproc=65536

$ cat /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
      <key>Label</key>
        <string>limit.maxfiles</string>
      <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
          <string>launchctl</string>
          <string>limit</string>
          <string>maxfiles</string>
          <string>200000</string>
          <string>200000</string>
        </array>
      <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
      <key>ServiceIPC</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
  </plist>
```

Comment: Hmm, strange: in my ElCap VM every user can change the open files limit with `ulimit -n *`.

Answer (score 3):

Having had this exact same problem, I ultimately found that my bash startup sequence (`.bashrc` or similar) was doing a `ulimit -n 1024`; and that caused both the soft *and* the **hard** limit to get set; the latter of which prevented any attempt at raising it afterwards, giving rise to the `"bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted"` error.

So, removing that command got the soft and hard limits restored to the apparent system defaults of `256` and `unlimited` respectively. The latter is what will enable you to `ulimit -n <whatever>` again.

In your case, assuming the cause is similar and your `Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist` is still in place as listed, I expect that `ulimit -Sn` and `ulimit -Hn` will report both to be `200000`.

Answer (score 1):

For me on macOS Mojave, I had to set both:

`.bash_profile`

```
ulimit -n 65536
```

`.bashrc`

```
ulimit -n 65536
```

If you only set from profile you can only increase from 256 to 1024.

It’s weird because there is not so much info about this online, I wonder how developers manage without it.